# Java: Inconsistent data sent over sockets with multiple local clients

Tags: java, sockets

I have developed what is effectively a chat server that can host any number of client connections. In addition to just sending strings, this server can also receive and relay 2 different java objects. In addition to propagating data received from a client to all other clients, the server itself can also send data.

I only have a single machine to test with, so testing has become difficult. With a single client, everything works exactly as expected. Next I tried 2 clients.

To facilitate all three applications running locally, the server manages two ServerSockets, each on a unique port. Each of the two clients then binds to a unique ServerSocket. Please let me know if this is incorrect or even unnecessary (Will a single ServerSocket will work for multiple local connections on the same port? I was unable to find the answer to this question.)With 2 clients and the server running, I begin to see issues.

Only the oldest client receives the updated version of one type of object, and only the newest client receives the updated version of the other type of object. All clients receive all chat messages.

To relay messages, I iterate over an ArrayList of ObjectOutputStreams. The data I am writing is the same for all streams, but the data received by the two clients differs. Is there something glaring wrong with this idea or do I need to keep digging through my code?

Comment: A single ServerSocket is enough for multiple clients. Get the specific clients with the accept()-method of ServerSocket and add them to an ArrayList or assign them to a variable so you can access them.

Comment: I have done this. Locally though, I can't have multiple clients connecting to the same port, correct?

Comment: You can't have two *servers* listening on the same port. But once a connection is established, you can have many clients connected to the same port.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

One issues was bug related. However, no, it is not possible to maintain two distinct socket connections when those two connections and the server all exist on the same machine using the same port.

Secondly, there seemed to be some consistency issues doing the following multiple times:

```
private void sendObject(ObjectOutputStream output) {

    try {
        output.writeObject(object);
        output.flush();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;     
}
```

This approach would cause the client to read the same object it read the last time the function was called. Creating a new object to send each time seems to have fixed this issue.

```
private void sendObject(ObjectOutputStream output) {

    try {
        output.writeObject(object);
        output.flush();
        output.reset();
    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return;     
}
```

Comment: Your second statement is incorrect as stated, and the solution to your last issue is `ObjectOutputStream.reset().`

Comment: interesting, I was not familiar with this. I will edit my answer. Why exactly is this necessary?

Answer (score 0):

One Server Socket is useful for lots of connections but not at the same time.
I don't know much about your software but it seems that you want to send to all of the clients all of the data but you are sending one packet to a different client (or consumer).

Make sure that you do not send data to one client and not to the other but to all of them.

Comment: What do you mean by 'but not once'?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I wanted to say "at the same time".

Comment: In that case you're wrong. Every concurrent Java server in the world uses `ServerSockets,` apart from those that use `ServerSocketChannels.`

Comment: But... one socket only can be connected to another socket, am I wrong? A thread can have lots of sockets but only one connection in a certain socket in a certain moment. Don't? I don't know about ServerSocketChannels. I Will investigate.

Comment: One server socket can accept many connections, and each `accept()` returns a different `Socket` which allows you to connect to multiple clients simultaneously.